# Node.js: request/response between master and workers using IPC

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, npm, ipc

I need the implementation of request/response between master and workers using IPC (inter-process communication).

This solution must be asynchronous: no any blocking while we awaiting response from worker.

Is there good solution in npm packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found great package *cluster-hub* https://www.npmjs.com/package/cluster-hub